# Página que necessita de login não entra mesmo com login autenticado

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Olá, estou estudando PHP e acabei ficando preso em um sistema de php com login utilizando sessões, eu queria que a pagina de login que eu criei me levasse para uma página somente para usuários, portanto eu fiz ela em um if que não permite que pessoas sem login entrem nela, mas depois de criá-la e testar eu percebi que mesmo as pessoas que estão logadas não conseguem entrar na página dos usuários, imagino que seja algum tipo de erro com as sessões já que o if inclui um `isset($_SESSION['id'])` como requerimento para poder ver a página. Códigos das páginas abaixo:

Validação de login:

```
include("../conexao.php");

$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$senha = md5($_POST["senha"]);

$busca = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = :usuario and senha = :senha";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($busca);
$stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario);
$stmt->bindParam(":senha", $senha);
$stmt->execute();
$linha = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$linha) {
    echo "esse usuario não existe";

}else{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $linha->id;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $linha->usuario;
    header("location:menu.php");
}

 ?>
```

Página de usuários:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {



 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Pagina Usuario</h2>
<br><br>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<a href="desconecta.php">desconectar</a>

<?php 

}else{

    header("location:desconecta.php");
} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Depois de mexer um pouco eu consegui uma mensagem de erro, tudo o que fiz foi tirar o `header(location:menu.php)` da página de validação, e agora eu obtenho 2 erros quando tento fazer o login:

[image]

Esses erros são referentes às duas ultimas linhas da página de validação, a linha `$_SESSION['id'] = $linha->id;` e a linha `$_SESSION['usuario'] = $linha->usuario;`

Comment: $linha não é um objeto, é uma array (porque que você usou fetchAll)

Comment: Marcos, faz como o bfavaretto falou. Tenta trocar pelo $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) pra ver se funciona.

Comment: Desculpe mas eu estou aprendendo ainda, teria como me explicar como ficaria essa linha do código pra que eu possa testar? Seria apenas trocar $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) para apenas fetch? Por que se for não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Consegui arrumar fazendo uma abordagem diferente, segui o que o bfavaretto disse e troquei `$linha = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` por `$linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, também alterei as linhas `$_SESSION['id'] = $linha->id;` e `$_SESSION['usuario'] = $linha->usuario;` por `$_SESSION['id'] = $linha['id'];` e `$_SESSION['usuario'] = $linha['usuario'];` respectivamente. Fiz alterações na minha página de usuarios para que pudesse utilizar um `if(isset($_GET['logout']))` na página de logout para destruir a sessão e não haver como alguém entrar na página dos usuários sem fazer login antes.